# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as array

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I cannot find the error here how do i fix this?

```
$db2 = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('Checkinout')
    ->join('Z_MemRecord','Checkinout.Userid','=','Z_MemRecord.uid')
    ->select(DB::raw("FORMAT(MAX (Checkinout.CheckTime), 'hh:mm tt') AS OffTime, FORMAT (min(Checkinout.CheckTime), 'hh:mm tt') AS Ontime, Checkinout.Userid,Z_MemRecord.Uname,FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'MMM dd yyyy') as dates,FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'dddd') as hour"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("Convert(Date, Checkinout.CheckTime),Checkinout.Userid,Z_MemRecord.Uname,FORMAT(Checkinout.CheckTime, 'MMM dd yyyy'),FORMAT (Checkinout.CheckTime, 'dddd')"));

$result = DB::connection('mysql')->table('netdoc')->insert(['Logid' => $db2['Checkinout.Userid'] ,'name'=> $db2['Z_MemRecord.Uname'],'dates' =>  $db2['dates'],'day'=>$db2['hour'],'Ontime' => $db2['Ontime'],'Offtime' => $db2['OffTime']]);


dd($db2);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? db2, mysql and sqlsrv give different indications.

Comment: i am using SQL Server MS 2018 and i just want to insert the modified data from sqlsrv to mysql.

Comment: `dd($db2);` before your `$result`. As the message says, it's a Builder object, you probably need to get results first using `->get()` first to access `Checkinout.Userid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `groupBy()` returns a `QueryBuilder` to convert it to an array call `get()` to receive an array of rows.

```
->groupBy(...)
->get();
```

Thou you need to deal with the query returning multiple rows, so an quick solution for that would to traverse db2 with `foreach()`.

```
foreach ($db2 as $row) {
    $row = (array) $row;

    $result = DB::connection('mysql')
        ->table('netdoc')
        ->insert(['Logid' => $row['Checkinout.Userid'] ,'name'=> $row['Z_MemRecord.Uname'],'dates' =>  $row['dates'],'day'=>$row['hour'],'Ontime' => $row['Ontime'],'Offtime' => $row['OffTime']]);
}
```

Comment: now it shows this error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

Comment: Laravel returns stdObjects i converted it to array i guess it will help :)

Comment: It works now! It does pass the all data i need! That's really a big help! omg. thank you very much. :D

Comment: ahm, one last question. how do i fix the duplicate something?  "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '40218' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: What is your primary key? usually that is set by the db

Comment: I fixed it by removing the userid from sqlsrv and using the Auto Increment id from mysql but i want to use the same id from sqlsrv to mysql

Comment: That is also the correct approach imo :) if it solved your problem please accept it as an answer at some point, have a nice day

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you very much for answering this question. It helps a lot :)